# What is causing the line break?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I am working on a blog: http://poweryogatrainings.blogspot.com/search. If you check the link you can see that currently the blog posts are just below the thumbnail. Now I am trying to make the blog posts align beside (on the right side of) the thumbnail but I am not sure how. Does anyone know what is causing the line break and what can I do to avoid it?

Also I think there was a website where you could edit codes of your website and watch the preview without actually changing the codes. Any ideas about it?

Comment: don't use H[1-6] header tags this way . These always add a new line . put the image inside the H3 tag or use div instead of H3 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add left float to the image, and give it some space to the right and bottom, as below:

```
img.postthumb {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, for your second question... If you're using Firefox - get the Firebug extension for in-context editing (Google: 'Firebug'). If using Chrome, right click 'Inspect Element' anywhere on the page and make your changes in the box that appears.

Comment: I dont use firefox but I do use the Inspect Element feature in Chrome. However, I think there was a website solely for that purpose which was much easier, but I cannot find it right now.

Comment: No, it was something else. You cannot edit the whole site in JS fiddle, can you?

Comment: Oh! it was CSS pivot, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` to place your contents on same line. Like `float:left;` for img tag will allow  contents to be displayed horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

if your thumbnails are all the same width, then you can do this:

```
article { overflow: hidden; /* or some other clearfix method */ }
article img.postthumb { float: left; }
article h3, article header, article div.postbody, article footer { margin-left: WIDTH_OF_IMAGE }
```

a few points:

- WIDTH_OF_IMAGE should be replaced by the actual width of your image, and possibly any extra space that you want to appear between it and the words of your article
- the code I've recommended will line things up in columns, if you want to avoid that, then just remove the third line of css and you will have flowing paragraphs which wrap the image
- there is a lot you could do to make your code a bit more consise, for instance your article's h3 tag should really be in your article's header tag etc. You also have `<title>` and `<meta>` tags in your body, when these are best placed in the `<head>` of your document..

anyway, good luck, I love yoga sites in general and, look forward to seeing the finished article